# Laravel 4 Jquery ajax cascade dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to populate a select box based on a previous select box value in Laravel 4. i think i have a logic problem :S

My Js `

```
    $('#cat').change(function(){
        category_id = $(this).val();
        $('#secondcat').empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:  '{{ URL::to('api/dropdown') }}',
            data: 'category_id ='+category_id ,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(veri){
            $.each(veri,function(i,deger){

                  $('#secondcat').append('<option value="'+deger.id+'">' +deger.name+ '<option>' );

                }); // each  

            },
            error:function(x,hata){
                alert("Hata Oluştu" +hata);
            }

        }); // ajax


     }); // change`
```

Route

```
Route::get('api/dropdown','admin_BasvuruController@ajaxislemi');
```

My ajaxislemi() method in my BasvuruController:

```
  public function ajaxislemi() {

        $category_id = Input::get('category_id');

        return Kampanya::where('category_id','==',$category_id)->get();

    }
```

in View my form :

```
<select class="form-control" name="category_id" id="cat" >
        <option value="" disabled selected> Please Select First </option>
        @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option  value="{{ $category->id }}"> {{ $category->name }} </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>



    <select  name="kampanya_adi" class="form-control" id="secondcat" >
        <option> </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I am sure there is a question in there somewhere, but i do not see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is your issue:

```
return Kampanya::where('category_id','==',$category_id)->get();
```

You have a double "==". It should be:

```
return Kampanya::where('category_id','=',$category_id)->get();
```